# How to correctly set up Palatino font with math (related to pxfonts)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, mathpazo

I've read many times here in TeX.SE that `pxfonts` has a lot of spacing inconsistencies, and that it's better to use `mathpazo`. The problem is that `mathpazo` doesn't load all the math symbols to match the font style. But `pxfonts` does, and, also adds a bold version of every symbol. Moreover, there exists the `tgpagella` package, which only loads the text font.

So here appears my first question: which is the *best* way of loading palatino (or a clone) fonts (I use LaTeX, not XeLaTeX)?

I suppose that the answer is `mathpazo` because of the problems of `pxfonts`. But I don't know what `tgpagella` offers that `mathpazo` doesn't.

And, my second problem. Once set up the palatino fonts (normal, italic, bold, … ), I want the math symbols (and math alphabets, like blackboard) of `pxfonts`. How can I do that? Do they suffer from spacing problems or not? If so, how can I solve it?

In short, **which is the best way of setting up palatino (or a palatino clone) fonts and `pxfonts` symbols?**

Comment: I think that now there is a tgpagella math font.

Comment: @Guido the package is `qpxmath` but it doesn't load all the symbols.

Comment: Indeed, the new font  is texgyrepagellamath.otf, but there is no support for LaTeX.

Comment: try the KP-fonts instead. `\usepackage{kpfonts}`

Comment: @Herbert I often use `kpfonts`, and I like it, but it is not palatino. And this is why I'm looking for a good implementation of palatino.

Comment: kpfonts are based on the the same fonts as TeXGyre Pagella, as far as I know.

Comment: @Herbert I know it, but it has all the glyphs modified. It's a bit similar, but far from being almost the same. More or less, I would like to have all the symbols from `kpfonts`, which are almost the same as `pxfonts` ones, but with Palatino fonts.

Comment: @Manuel: and where is the problem to load first `kpfonts` and then `tgpagella`?

Comment: @Herbert `tgpagella` doesn't provide math fonts.

Comment: @sigh ... the reason why you should load kpfonts first!

Comment: @Herbert but then I don't have palatino fonts in math.

Comment: there are _no_ free math palatino fonts in Type 1! you have to buy one or use xelatex or using some substitution like kpfonts.

Comment: @Herbert Well, may be I'm wrong, but with `mathpazo` or `pxfonts` you get math fonts.

Comment: no! that are always replacements from other fonts. Read the introduction from the `pxfonts` documentation

Comment: @Herbert Mmm, what I'm looking for is `pxfonts` symbols with palatino fonts (i.e., all `mathpazo` except symbols, which would be taken from `pxfonts`). But if this is not possible (because of `pxfonts` spacing problems), a good approximation would be all `mathpazo` with `kpfonts` symbols. **EDIT:** in the `pxfonts` documentation I see `math alphabets using Adobe Palatino (or URWPalladioL) with modified metrics`.

Comment: `mathpazo` _is_ palatino with math symbols from different fonts. Load `kpfonts` first and then package `palatino` or first `pxfonts` and then `tgpagella`

Comment: @Herbert `kpfonts,palatino` doesn't change the `\mathnormal` font. And `pxfonts,tgpagella` is what I'm using right now, but this is part of the question: *which is the best way of loading palatino fonts with `pxfonts` symbols?*. Do `pxfonts` symbols and `\mathnormal` suffer from spacing problems? If not, probably this is the best way of loading it (and you could post your answer), but I don't know. Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a new font, called [New PX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newpx/), which seems to resolve most issues.

This package is meant to be a replacement for Young Ryu’s pxfonts—a complete text and math package with roman text font provided by a Palatino clone, sans serif based on a Helvetica clone, typewriter faces, plus math symbol fonts whose math italic letters are from a Palatino Italic clone.
As with the related txfonts (though not as severe) the math metrics in pxfonts are overly tight.
The goal of this new project is use those existing glyphs along with a few additions and with completely reworked metrics which are generally looser, but not as loose as Computer Modern math. The following small examples (double normal size) provide some idea of the extent of the changes.

[image: pxfonts—newpxmath comparison]

This pack­age, based on px­fonts, pro­vides many fixes and en­hance­ments to that pack­age, split­ting it in two parts —new­px­text and new­px­math— which may be run in­de­pen­dently of one an­other. It pro­vides scal­ing, im­proved met­rics, and other op­tions. For proper op­er­a­tion, the pack­ages re­quire that the pack­ages newtx­math and px­fonts be in­stalled and their map files en­abled.

Here is the [CTAN download page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newpx).

Comment: Is it better to use TeX Gyre Pagella or NewPX fonts? I'm looking for something opentype looking like Palatino, with maths and compatible with kerning options.

Comment: @skan [NewPX appears in the list of fonts with math support](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html), whereas TeX Gyre Pagella does not.

Comment: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/index_html and Esteis answer also speaks about the math option with Tex-Gyre-Pagella

Comment: @skan [It is impossible to typeset “real” mathematical papers using only TeX Gyre fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math/index_html), because so far math symbols are scarcely represented.

Comment: then what opentype font would you suggest?, Maybe newpx?

Comment: @skan Evidently & thank you in advance for giving out a point!

Comment: What about kpfonts vs newpx? What advantages has one over the other one.

Comment: @skan Comparing the text examples, [New PX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newpx/) seems to do a better job at kerning —horizontal spacing between letters in the same word— than [KP Serif](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kpserif/). However, that might be a matter of personal taste.

Comment: What do you thing about this comment? "The opentype fonts in newpx appear to be opentype wrappers for the type 1 fonts, still in legacy TeX 8bit encoding, not Unicode fonts with an OpenType MATH table, so they are not OpenType math fonts in the sense that is required here. (Unless I missed a new font with a Math table?)" github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/373#issuecomment-2786090‌​91

Comment: @Serge Stroobandt How do you use newpxmath to render pxfonts style integrals? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643069/how-to-set-newpxmath-to-use-the-pxfonts-integral

Answer (score 8):

**Edit: this answer works for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but Manuel explicitly stated he wanted to use plain 'LaTeX' (i.e. the TeX or pdfTeX engine?). My mistake. I know nothing about T1 fonts, alas.**

TeX Gyre Pagella has a [math font](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/index_html) nowadays. I can't speak to matters of spacing, but I very much trust the [GUST e-foundry](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry) to do such things properly. After all, TeX Gyre and Latin Modern (which the GUST e-foundry is also responsible for) are pretty important projects.

Below is the skeleton of the TeX Gyre Pagella Math test file. I'm mostly use ConTeXt these days, but I think these three lines are the essential ones:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

Here is the entire skeleton and a picture of its output. For the math code, see `math-test.tex` in the font's zip file. ([TeX Gyre Math page](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/index_html), click through to the download page.)

```
%% This is a test file for LaTeX/Unicode-Math for both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}[2000/07/18] %% Displayed equations
\usepackage{amssymb}[2002/01/22] %% and additional symbols

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

% math math math

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I wanted (I've already set up my fonts) to do in LaTeX, not in XeLaTeX. Finally, I decided to go for `\usepackage{mathpazo,mathabx}` (with a few glyphs taken from other fonts). But, of course I like `Asana Math` and `TG Pagella Math` for XeLaTeX.

Comment: Gah, my eyes totally missed that. Sorry!

Comment: Is it better to use TeX Gyre Pagella or NewPX or Asana fonts in Luatex? I'm looking for something opentype looking like Palatino, with maths and compatible with kerning options.