# How to set `newpxmath` to use the `pxfonts` integral

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I want to know how to set `newpxmath` to use the `pxfonts` integral, which is just like the **Wolfram** fonts. Now I use `Asana-Math` as a substitute. I want `\int` like this:

[image]

But `newpxmath` default is this:

[image]

which `upint` selects upright integrals like these:

[image]

and `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` is this:

[image]

Look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119549/231103) by @Serge Stroobandt which seems possible to load the `pxfonts` integral, **But I don't know how to set it.**

And I found `texdoc newpxmath` say this:

> CHANGES AS OF VERSION 1.5
>
> > This `newpx` package differs from `pxfonts` in the following ways:
> >
> > > for those who do not like the integral in `pxfonts`, an emboldened version of the Computer Modern integral is made available, matching the weight of the `pxfonts` symbols;

> `cmintegrals` instructs `newpxmath` to load a thicker version of the Computer Modern integral in place of the `newpxmath` default—the `pxfonts` integral (identical to the integral in the **Wolfram** fonts), which is not to everyone’s taste—a consequence is that none of the special forms of `pxfonts` integrals are available; As of version 1.3, this option does nothing, as the new default is slanted integrals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pxfonts` integrals with `newpxmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsPX}{U}{pxexa}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsPX}{bold}{U}{pxexa}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{pxexa}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\idotsintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{39}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{41}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{43}
\newcommand\varointctrclockwise{\varointctrclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varointclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{62}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{64}
\newcommand\oiintctrclockwise{\oiintctrclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{66}
\newcommand\varoiintclockwise{\varoiintclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{68}
\newcommand\oiiintctrclockwise{\oiiintctrclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{70}
\newcommand\varoiiintclockwise{\varoiiintclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{72}
\newcommand\oiintclockwise{\oiintclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{74}
\newcommand\varoiintctrclockwise{\varoiintctrclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{76}
\newcommand\oiiintclockwise{\oiiintclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{78}
\newcommand\varoiiintctrclockwise{\varoiiintctrclockwiseop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{80}
\newcommand\sqiint{\sqiintop\nolimits}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsPX}{82}
\newcommand\sqiiint{\sqiiintop\nolimits}

\begin{document}

\[
\fint
\iiiint
\iiint
\iint
\oiiint
\oiiintclockwise
\oiiintctrclockwise
\oiint
\]
\[
\oiintclockwise
\oiintclockwise
\oiintctrclockwise
\ointctrclockwise
\sqiiint
\sqiint
\sqint
\]
\[
\varoiiintclockwise
\varoiiintctrclockwise
\varoiintclockwise
\varoiintctrclockwise
\varointclockwise
\varointctrclockwise
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the same as with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
\fint
\iiiint
\iiint
\iint
\oiiint
\oiiintclockwise
\oiiintctrclockwise
\oiint
\]
\[
\oiintclockwise
\oiintclockwise
\oiintctrclockwise
\ointctrclockwise
\sqiiint
\sqiint
\sqint
\]
\[
\varoiiintclockwise
\varoiiintctrclockwise
\varoiintclockwise
\varoiintctrclockwise
\varointclockwise
\varointctrclockwise
\]

\end{document}
```

Without all those lines, instead, some of the symbols are unavailable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\fint
\iiiint
\iiint
\iint
\oiiint
\oiiintclockwise
\oiiintctrclockwise
\oiint
\]
\[
\oiintclockwise
\oiintclockwise
\oiintctrclockwise
\ointctrclockwise
\sqiiint
\sqiint
\sqint
\]
\[
\varoiiintclockwise
\varoiiintctrclockwise
\varoiintclockwise
\varoiintctrclockwise
\varointclockwise
\varointctrclockwise
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Addition of new slanted and upright integrals, replacing those in versions prior to 1.5`

This is what `README` of `newtxmath` said. So I think it is impossible to use the old integral sign.